# SSIS how to compare time field

Tags: time, ssis, compare

I get a time column which is in DT_DBTime type. (e.g.05:00:21.0000000). Now I need to compare this time column with specific time slot. However, it shows errors when I write in this way:

```
[Time]>="05:00:00.0000000"&&[Time]<="05:01:00.0000000"
```

Is there any way I could compare time values without converting to string type?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to cast your string and compare that way:

```
[Time] >= (DT_DBTime)"05:00:00.0000000" && [Time] <= (DT_DBTime)"05:01:00.0000000"
```

If that doesn't work, trying using CONVERT:

```
[Time] >= CONVERT(DATETIME,"05:00:00.0000000") && [Time] <= CONVERT(DATETIME,"05:01:00.0000000")
```